# Why can't I bind a single event to multiple selectors in one statement in Backbone's View events?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the following Backbone View:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      'change [name="title"], change [name="body"]': 'onChangeEvent'
    },

    onChangeEvent: function (e) {
       // fires only for change [name="title"] event
    }
});
```

I need to bind `onChangeEvent` method to both `change [name="title"]` and `change [name="body"]` events. But `onChangeEvent` method is invoked only for `change [name="title"]` event but not for `change [name="body"]`.

Please help me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>   [...] Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`.

so the event in question is the first space-delimited component of the key in the `events` object. Applying that to what you have gives `'change'` as the event and `[name="title"], change [name="body"]` as the selector; furthermore, a comma is a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) so your selector (as Backbone sees it) is looking for things with `name="title"` attributes or `<change>` elements with `name="body"` attributes. You don't have any `<change>` elements but you do have `name="title"` elements, hence the event triggering behavior you're seeing.

You can use one event entry with a multiple selector:

```
events: {
  'change [name="title"], [name="body"]': 'onChangeEvent'
  // -------------------^ but no extra 'change'
}
```

or two separate event entries:

```
events: {
  'change [name="title"]': 'onChangeEvent',
  'change [name="body"]' : 'onChangeEvent'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Be careful with multiple event entries though. If both selectors match an element, the event will be handled twice. Comma separation is the safer approach.